Joining tables with different date formats (Literal does not match format string)
I'm trying to join two Oracle tables (basically to pull in a daily rate against the date in another table), but the table I'm pulling the date from has the timestamp in it.  I'm seeing a lot of solutions for the "Literal does not match format string" problems, but they all seem to be for entering a date directly instead of joining from another table.  Apologies if I didn't understand the earlier solutions correctly, but I'm very novice to SQL.   My code currently is basically:
select gdr.conversion_rate as "Rate", pa.agreement_date as "agreement Rate Date"
 from apps.gl_daily_rates gdr, apps.project_agreements pa    
where gdr.rate_date = pa.agreement_date

With the pa.agreement_date value being the one with the extra times stamp in it.  I tried using the todate function around the pa.agreement_date in the join but was definitely not doing it correctly, if that's the proper solution.
Thanks!

Please show how at least the 2 columns are defined and sample data.

Not sure if this is what you're asking, but the gdr.rate_date format is:
21-MAY-01
22-MAY-01
23-MAY-01
24-MAY-01
25-MAY-01
29-MAY-01
30-MAY-01
31-MAY-01
and the pa.agreement_date format is:
2010/06/30 00:00:00
2010/04/26 00:00:00
2010/04/23 00:00:00
2008/10/31 00:00:00
2008/10/31 00:00:00
2009/05/13 00:00:00

[Edit] your question and post the details from your comment. When someone asks you for more details, they want you to add those details to the question itself. Use markdown to properly format [database] table data.

please show all your table DDLs

Not sure how I find this?  I'm extremely new to SQL queries.

Run DESCRIBE apps.gl_daily_rates and DESCRIBE apps.project_agreements or look at the CREATE TABLE statements you used to create the tables and then [edit] the details into the question.

So, basically the date in the agreements table is type VARCHAR2(150) and the one in the daily rates table is DATE?  There's dozens of other objects in each table.

Please [edit] your question and include a [MRE] with the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data; an English (not code) explanation of the logic that you want to implement; the complete error message for your code; and the expected output (formatted using markdown) for your sample data. Please do NOT keep putting updates in comments when they should be part of your question.

You appear to have two tables, one with a DATE column and one with a VARCHAR2(150) column:
CREATE TABLE apps.gl_daily_rates(rate_date DATE, conversion_rate NUMBER);

CREATE TABLE apps.project_agreements (agreement_date VARCHAR2(150));

and the sample data from your comment:
INSERT INTO apps.gl_daily_rates (rate_date, conversion_rate)
SELECT DATE '2001-05-21', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2001-05-22', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2001-05-23', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2001-05-24', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2001-05-25', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2001-05-29', 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2001-05-30', 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2001-05-31', 8 FROM DUAL;

INSERT INTO apps.project_agreements (agreement_date)
SELECT '2010/06/30 00:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2010/04/26 00:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2010/04/23 00:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2008/10/31 00:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2008/10/31 00:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2009/05/13 00:00:00' FROM DUAL

Then when you run your query:
SELECT gdr.conversion_rate as "Rate",
       pa.agreement_date as "agreement Rate Date"
FROM   apps.gl_daily_rates gdr
       INNER JOIN apps.project_agreements pa    
       ON gdr.rate_date = TO_DATE(pa.agreement_date, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')

It "works" but produces no output. This is because the dates you are joining on do not match.
If you have dates that do match into the table:
INSERT INTO apps.project_agreements (agreement_date)
SELECT '2001/05/21 00:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2001/05/22 00:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2001/05/23 00:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2001/05/24 00:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2001/05/25 00:00:00' FROM DUAL;

and re-run the SELECT query then your query will work and generate the output:



Rate
agreement Rate Date




1
2001-05-21 00:00:00.000000


2
2001-05-22 00:00:00.000000


3
2001-05-23 00:00:00.000000


4
2001-05-24 00:00:00.000000


5
2001-05-25 00:00:00.000000



fiddle

So, I'd have to do this for every date in the table?  What I pasted were just the first few records, each table includes basically every date, which is why the to_date solutions from other threads on here didn't seem appropriate.

@EYU If you want to join on the dates then you need to have matching dates for them to join. If the INNER JOINed tables do not have anything matching on  one side of the join then those rows will not show up. If you want all rows on one side of the join to appear regardless of whether there is a match on the other side then use an OUTER JOIN rather than an INNER JOIN. What logic were you expecting to implement?

DATE datatype in Oracle containes 7 bytes (for century, year, month, day, hour, minute and second) and there is ALWAYS a time component contained. That is not a timestamp cause the TIMESTAMP in Oracle is a separate datatype.
When you join tables on any columns be sure that the left and right side of the condition are of the same type. Doing so, when values (of the same datatype) match then you have joined rows of data from both tables.
When dealing with dates it is best to have DATE datatype. When that is not the case (one column is DATE the other VARCHAR2) convert the non-date column to DATE keeping in mind time component of the datatype (default is 00:00:00).
Never use To_Date() function on data that already is of DATE datatype.
Here is the code to get your result with different join ON options.
Additional comments in the code:
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
   gl_daily_rates (RATE_DATE, CONVERSION_RATE) AS
    ( Select To_Date('2001-05-21', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 1 From Dual Union All
      Select To_Date('2001-05-22', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 2 From Dual Union All
      Select To_Date('2001-05-23', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 3 From Dual Union All
      Select To_Date('2001-05-24', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 4 From Dual Union All
      Select To_Date('2001-05-25', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 5 From Dual Union All
      Select To_Date('2001-05-29', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 6 From Dual Union All
      Select To_Date('2001-05-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 7 From Dual Union All
      Select To_Date('2001-05-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 8 From Dual Union All
      Select To_Date('2009-05-13', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 9 From Dual 
    ),
  project_agreements (AGREEMENT_DATE) AS
    ( Select '2010/06/30 00:00:00' From Dual Union All
      Select '2010/04/26 00:00:00' From Dual Union All
      Select '2010/04/23 00:00:00' From Dual Union All
      Select '2008/10/31 00:00:00' From Dual Union All
      Select '2008/10/31 00:00:00' From Dual Union All
      Select '2009/05/13 00:00:00' From Dual
    )

--    S Q L :
Select      gdr.CONVERSION_RATE "Rate", 
            pa.AGREEMENT_DATE "Agreement_Rate_Date"
From        gl_daily_rates gdr
Left Join   project_agreements pa 
    -- Different options for ON clause condition (dates are prefered)
    -- use just one of them, ofcourse
         -- ON   DATE datatype       (1)  works with sample data cause time for both columns are all 00:00:00
            ON( To_Date(pa.AGREEMENT_DATE, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') = gdr.RATE_DATE  )
         
         -- ON   DATE datatype       (2)  -- when joining on dates regardless time component
            ON( TRUNC(To_Date(pa.AGREEMENT_DATE, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')) = TRUNC(gdr.RATE_DATE  ))
            
         -- ON   VARCHAR2  datatype
            ON( SubStr(pa.AGREEMENT_DATE, 1, 10) = To_Char(gdr.RATE_DATE, 'yyyy/mm/dd'  ) )
          
         -- ON   NUMBER  datatype
            ON( To_Number(Replace(SubStr(pa.AGREEMENT_DATE, 1, 10), '/', '')) = To_Number(To_Char(gdr.RATE_DATE, 'yyyymmdd'  )) )
Order By    gdr.RATE_DATE

The above SQL uses Left (Outer) Join to see all the rates and just matching Agreement_Rate_Date:
/*    R e s u l t :    (Left Join)
Rate    Agreement_Rate_Date
----    -------------------
   1    null
   2    null
   3    null
   4    null
   5    null
   6    null
   7    null
   8    null                   
   9    2009/05/13 00:00:00  */

... if you want to see just matching rows use an Inner Join instead
/*    R e s u l t :    (Inner Join)
Rate    Agreement_Rate_Date
----    -------------------
   9    2009/05/13 00:00:00  */

See the fiddle here.
NOTE
Do not use list of tables syntax as it was deprecated for 30+ years now - use Join ON syntax.

Based on the comments you have agreement_date as a VARCHAR, and rate_date as a DATE. In this case you need to cast to date only a VARCHAR column.
SELECT
  gdr.conversion_rate as "Rate",
  pa.agreement_date as "agreement Rate Date"
FROM apps.gl_daily_rates gdr
JOIN apps.project_agreements pa
  ON gdr.rate_date = TO_DATE(pa.agreement_date, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') 

Side note, I believe it's better to avoid adding several tables after the FROM, and use JOIN instead.

I seem to be getting the error "ORA-01821: date format not recognized" with this code; I assume it might be due to the agreement date format being VARCHAR2(150)?

@EYU No, you NEVER use TO_DATE on a column that is already a DATE (or a TIMESTAMP). You want to use TO_DATE on the string column but not on the DATE column.

Great!  I removed the TO_DATE function on the first object from the rate table and that worked!

Updated the answer based on the new information provided.
